# Docker Compose with Angular, Express.js and Nginx - 502 response

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, nginx, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: "mongo:latest"
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
  backend:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./backend:/app
    environment:
      - MONGOHOST=cluster0-ipauv.mongodb.net
      - MONGOPORT=27017
      - MONGODATABASE=node-express
      - MONGOUSER=USER
      - MONGOPASSWORD=password
  frontend:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./frontend/:/app
```

nginx/default.conf

```
upstream frontend{
    server frontend:4200 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    keepalive 32;
}

upstream backend{
    server backend:3000 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s; 
    keepalive 32;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  frontend;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
    }

    location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }


}
```

nginx/Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

The error I am getting When I load URL : http://localhost:5000

```
[error] 6#6: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: frontend, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.2:4200/", host: "localhost:5000"
```

Comment: One suggesstion is use ngnix server to deploy your fronted application. I doubt your build is not successfull.

Comment: see this if this can helpl you https://serverfault.com/questions/317393/connect-failed-111-connection-refused-while-connecting-to-upstream

Comment: thanks for the link, I checked but looks like that didn't work for me. also can you please elaborate more on user Nginx server to deploy front end application. as I am new to docker.

also, when I run "docker-compose up --build", I am not getting any error.

Comment: Yes, I can, Once I create one example I Will let you know!

Comment: Hey, fixed the issue by adding "--host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true" in package.json of angular, so now the command is "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late replay. I hope you found the answer to your problem.
i.e:  in angular app package.json added `--host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true` and command used to start the app is `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true`

But as I promised, I created one repository, which can help you to build/setup the local development environment.
Have a look to the repository.
https://github.com/dupinder/NgnixDockerizedDevEnv

This example shows how to establish communication between the UI App and the backend application, Using Ngnix reverse proxy strategy. So no need to follow the hard bind-address.

Comment: thanks for your help, as I am working on my local I don't want to build frontend, but I can surely use your concept for staging environment

Comment: In production what you are using for UI App? CDN?

Comment: I am developing one of the test project, but anyway I am going to use UI App